# Gauging a web browser's bandwidth

Tags: performance, http, tcp, network-protocols, bandwidth

Is it possible to gauge a web browsers upload and/or download speed by monitoring normal http requests? Ideally a web application would be able to tell the speed of a client without any modifications and without client-side scripting like JavaScript/Java/Flash.  So even if a client was accessing the service with a library like Curl it would still work.  If this is possible, how?  If its not possible,  why?  How accurate can this method be?

(If it helps assume PHP/Apache,  but really this is a platform independent question.  Also being able to gauge the upload speed is more important to me.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Overview

You're asking for what is commonly called "passive" available bandwidth (ABW) measurement along a path (versus measuring a single link's ABW).  There are a number of different techniques<sup>1</sup> that estimate bandwidth using passive observation, or low-bandwidth "Active" ABW probing techniques.  However, the most common algorithms used in production services are *active* ABW techniques; they observe packet streams from two different end-points.

I'm most familiar with [`yaz`](https://github.com/jsommers/yaz), which sends packets from one side and measures variation in delay on the other side.  The one-sided passive path ABW measurement techniques are considered more experimental; there aren't solid implementations of the algorithms AFAIK.

### Discussion

The problem with the task you've asked for is that *all* non-intrusive<sup>2</sup> ABW measurement techniques rely on *timing*.  Sadly, timing is a very tricky thing when working with http...

- You have to deal with the reality of [object caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache) (for instance, [akamai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies#Content_delivery_to_a_user)) and [http proxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) (which terminate your TCP session prematurely and often spoof the web-server's IP address to the client).
- You have to deal with web-hosts which may get intermittently slammed

Finally, active ABW techniques rely on a structured packet stream (wrt packet sizes and timing), unlike what you see in a standard http transfer.

### Summary

In summary, unless you set up dedicated client / server / protocol just for ABW measurement, I think you'll be rather frustrated with the results.  You can keep your ABW socket connections on TCP/80, but the tools I have seen won't use http<sup>3</sup>.

*Editorial note*: My original answer suggested that ABW with http was possible.  On further reflection, I changed my mind.

---

END-NOTES:
---

1. See [Sally Floyd's archive of end-to-end TCP/IP bandwidth estimation tools](http://www.icir.org/models/tools.html)
2. The most common intrusive techniques (such as [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/)) use a flash or java applet in the browser to send & receive 3-5 parallel TCP streams to each endpoint for 20-30 seconds.  Add the streams' average throughput (not including lost packets requiring retransmission) over time, and you get that path's tx and rx ABW.  This is obviously pretty disruptive to VoIP calls, or any downloads in progress.  Disruptive meausurements are called bulk transfer capacity (BTC).  See [RFC 3148: A Framework for Defining Empirical Bulk Transfer Capacity Metrics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3148).  BTC measurements often use HTTP, but BTC doesn't seem to be what you're after.
3. That is good, since it removes the risk of in-line caching by denying http caches an object to cache; although some tools (like [`yaz`](https://github.com/jsommers/yaz)) are udp-only.

Answer (score 6):

Due to [the way TCP connections adapt to available bandwidth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_avoidance_algorithm), no this is not possible.  Requests are small and typically fit within one or two packets.  You need a least a dozen full-size packets to get even a coarse bandwidth estimate, since TCP first has to scale up to available bandwidth ("TCP slow start"), and you need to average out jitter effects.  If you want any accuracy, you're probably talking hundreds of packets required.  That's why upload rate measurement scripts typically transfer several megabytes of data.

OTOH, you might be able to estimate round-trip delay from the three-way handshake and the timing of acks.  But download speed has at least as much impact as upload speed.

Answer (score 3):

There's no support in javascript or any browser component to measure upload performance.

The only way I can think of is if you are uploading to a page/http handler, and the page is receiving the incoming bytes, it can measure how many bytes it is receiving per second. Then store that in some application wide dictionary with a session ID.

Then from the browser you can periodically poll the server to get the value in the dictionary using the session ID and show it to user. This way you can tell how's the upload speed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [AJAXOMeter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ajaxometer/), a JavaScript library which meassures your up- and download speed. You can see a live demo [here](https://www.tess-kom.de/speed-test).

Comment: it's give me wrong result , due to speedtest.net my currect speed is down : 890 KB/s , up : 564 KB/s but AJAXOMeter show , down : 178 KB/s and up : 134 KB/s

Answer (score 3):

That is not feasible in general as in-bound and out-bound bandwidth frequently is not symmetric. Different ISPs have significantly different ratios here that can vary on even time of the day basis.